# C++ Cmake doesn't set compiler language standard on Travis CI server

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci

I am developing an own open source programming language interpreter project and I can make silly mistakes as I am not sophisticated in `Cmake` and I am trying `Travis CI` for the first time. My project compiles on my `PC` (running `Ubuntu 16.04LTS`, `GCC 8.1` and `Cmake 3.12.0-rc2`) from bash terminal by executing `scripts/build_all.sh` and tests are executed by `scripts/run_tests.sh`.
Build script creates a `cmake-build-debug` directory, runs cmake and than builds and executes simple `cmake-build-debug/lexertl_gen/lexert_gen.out` program to generate a header file in my `include` folder for the main project. After that it builds the main project alongside with it's tests all under compiler option `std=gnu++2a`.

Here are all my `CMakeLists.txt` (the problem is described bellow):

**Root CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0)

set(INCLUDE_ROOT "/usr/local/include")
set(BOOST_ROOT   "${INCLUDE_ROOT}/boost_1_67_0")
set(LEXERTL_ROOT "${INCLUDE_ROOT}/lexertl")
set(GTEST_ROOT   "${INCLUDE_ROOT}/googletest")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -std=gnu++2a -Werror \
                     -Wno-error=variadic-macros \
                     -Werror=implicit-fallthrough")

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
include_directories(include ${BOOST_ROOT} ${LEXERTL_ROOT} ${GTEST_ROOT})

add_library(calamity_core ${SOURCES})

    project(lexer.out)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main_lexer.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} m calamity_core)

    project(parser.out)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main_parser.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} m calamity_core)

    project(tests.out)
    add_subdirectory(tests)

    project(lexertl_gen.out)
    add_subdirectory(lexertl_gen)
```

**tests/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -std=gnu++2a -Werror \
                     -Wno-error=variadic-macros \
                     -Werror=implicit-fallthrough")

add_subdirectory(/usr/local/include/googletest ../gtets-build)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} gtest gtest_main gmock calamity_core)
```

**lexertl_gen/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -std=gnu++2a -Werror \
                     -Wno-error=variadic-macros \
                     -Werror=implicit-fallthrough")

set(SOURCES ../src/token.cpp
            ../src/var_substring.cpp
            ../src/cui.cpp
            ../src/message_exception.cpp)

add_executable(lexertl_gen.out main_lexertl_gen.cpp ${SOURCES})
```

Ultimately, I decided to add `Travis CI` to my project. I wrote a `bootstrap.sh` script to install and configure all dependencies (I also install `GCC 8.1`, because default `GCC 4.8.4` installed on `Travis CI` server doesn't support `gnu++2a`). This script works well, but when it comes to running `scripts/build_all.sh` on `Travis CI` server GCC fails to set `gnu++2a` for compiling my main project with tests, it complains about using `inline` variables, `std::is_integral` and other modern C++ stuff, explicitly mentioning that those features are supported under `std=c++17` or `std=gnu++17`. [Here is the link to my latest unsuccessful build on Travis CI.](https://travis-ci.com/VitahaKryvenko/calamity_interpreter)

I don't get it, as I updated `GCC` and my first simple code generator program runs well (though if I remove `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` from `tests/CMakeLists.txt` this program compiles on my `PC` but doesn't compile on `Travis CI` server either). What's wrong am I doing here? Is it because of the `Cmake 3.9` which Travis uses?

My `.travis.yml` configuration file:

```
language: cpp
sudo: required
dist: trusty
compiler:
- g++
os:
- linux
script:
- ./bootstrap.sh; cd scripts; ./build_all.sh; ./run_tests.sh
env:
  global:
  - LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      addons:
        apt:
          compiler: gcc
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-8
          env: COMPILER=g++-8
```

[Link to my project on GitHub.](https://github.com/VitahaKryvenko/calamity_interpreter) (sorry for empty `README.md`)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've finally solved a problem by making `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` a cache variable:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -std=gnu++2a -Werror \
                     -Wno-error=variadic-macros \
                     -Werror=implicit-fallthrough"
                    CACHE STRING "compiler flags")
```

Though I don't think it is a beautiful solution and I still can't understand why it compiled on my `PC` but not on `Travis CI`